# Замена повторяющегося выражения console.log('var = ',var);

Tags: javascript

Постоянно использую для отладки выражение вида

```
var a = 5;
console.log('a =', a); // результат в консоли а = 5
```

Это выражение приходится писать вручную сотни раз. Я пытался написать функцию для упрощения работы, но для этого нужно получать имя переменной в виде строки, а это очень запутанный и "неправильный" способ как я понял. Как мне упростить и ускорить отладку, не писать это выражение каждый раз? Пишу через NotePad++.

И смежный вопрос: Можете порекомендовать какое-нибудь видео где показана правильная, профессиональная отладка кода javascript с практической стороны?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function myLog(obj) {
  for (var prop in obj)
    console.log(prop + ' =', obj[prop], '(' + typeof obj[prop] + ')'); 
}

var a = 5;
myLog({a});
```

Comment: Т.е. если переменную разобрать по свойствам как объект, то у нее будет единственное свойство - имя в виде строки, я правильно понял?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov да, если передавать ее внутри объекта `{a}` (или `{ a: a }`)

Comment: А почему `for ... in` работает без фигурных скобок?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov Не понял. Какой `for ... in` работает без фигурных скобок?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov А-а-а. Фигурные скобки обязательно нужны, только если блок кода в цикле включает больше одной строки.

Comment: @Igor, не одной строки, а больше одного statement :)

Answer (score 1):

По `console.log` вам уже ответили, я попробую дополнить ответ по дебагу.

Правильный дебаг в JS - это инструкция `debugger` в коде, либо `breakpoint` во вкладке Source в консоли браузера. Оба способа дают одну и ту же информацию, а главные их плюсы в том, что вы видите сразу все переменные в текущей области видимости, а так же можете запускать выполнение по шагам и видеть все результаты вычислений, либо стартовать запуск до следующего `breakpoint'а`

Про использование есть тонные видео на ютубе, гуглятся без каких либо проблем. Все примерно одинаковые, посмотрев два-три вы поймете, что к чему